# How to display php output as xml

Tags: php, xml, glob

I have this simple php that outputs a list of all the png files in a directory.  Is there a way to take this list and make it xml?

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename " ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the format of XML that you want. This would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php
foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    echo "<png>$filename</png>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not a php programmer so I'm not sure, but if there is an xml object in php, it's best to use that rather than strings. the object will usually take care of encoding, for example if $filename contains <, >, & those need to be encoded or the xml is invalid.

Comment: Don't forget to put on the first line the code: header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

Comment: @aephous: `echo '<png>', htmlspecialchars($filename), '</png>';`. Generating XML by dom manipulation is a major pain the arse. direct string output with appropriate treatment of text is by far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Render it manually?

```
<?php
$xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><directory>';

foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    $xmlStr .= '<file>' . $filename . '</file>';
}
$xmlStr .= '</directory>';

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xmlStr;
?>
```